# tensorflow/keras lstm input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to learn the keras functional API through the [tutorials](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) from Keras, and when I try to modify the example,  I seem to get a shape mismatch. The only difference between the tutorial code and the one below is that I remove the embedding layer since mine is a regression problem.

Firstly, I am aware that LSTM expects 3 dimensions. In my example, I have:

```
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE=32
MODEL_INPUT_BATCH_SIZE=128

headline_data = np.random.uniform(low=1, high=9000, size=(MODEL_INPUT_BATCH_SIZE, 100)).astype(np.float32)
additional_data = np.random.uniform(low=1, high=9000, size=(MODEL_INPUT_BATCH_SIZE, 5)).astype(np.float32)
labels = np.random.randint(0, 1 + 1, size=(MODEL_INPUT_BATCH_SIZE, 1))

main_input = Input(shape=(100,), dtype='float32', name='main_input')

lstm_out = LSTM(32)(main_input)

auxiliary_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(lstm_out)

auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(5,), name='aux_input')
x = keras.layers.concatenate([lstm_out, auxiliary_input])

# We stack a deep densely-connected network on top
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

# And finally we add the main logistic regression layer
main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

# This defines a model with two inputs and two outputs:
model = Model(inputs=[main_input, auxiliary_input], outputs=[main_output, auxiliary_output])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                loss={'main_output': 'binary_crossentropy', 'aux_output': 'binary_crossentropy'},
                loss_weights={'main_output': 1., 'aux_output': 0.2})

# And trained it via:
model.fit({'main_input': headline_data, 'aux_input': additional_data},
                {'main_output': labels, 'aux_output': labels},
                epochs=2, batch_size=TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE)
```

When I run the above, I get:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

So, I tried changing my input shape like so:

```
main_input = Input(shape=(100,1), dtype='float64', name='main_input')
```

and when I run this, I get:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected main_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (128, 100)
```

I am perplexed and lost as to where the error is coming from. Would really appreciate some guidance on this.

*EDIT*

I have also tried setting:

```
headline_data = np.expand_dims(headline_data, axis=2)
```

and then used,

```
main_input = Input(shape=headline_data.shape, dtype='float64', name='main_input')
```

then, I get:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

seems really strange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Your problem is with the shape of your data.

```
headline_data = np.random.uniform(low=1, high=9000, size=(MODEL_INPUT_BATCH_SIZE, 100))
headline_data.shape
```

returns

```
(128,100)
```

However this should have three dimensions.

Without doublechecking you probably need to do something like:

```
headline_data.reshape(128,1,100)
```

Have a look at this post, it should clear everything up.

[Link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/)

*** UPDATE ***

Do the following:

```
headling_data = healdine_data.reshape(128,1,100)
main_input = Input(shape=(1,100), dtype='float32', name='main_input')
```

I tested it and it works, so let me know if it doesnt for you =)

---- Complete Code: ----

```
import numpy as np

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense


TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE=32
MODEL_INPUT_BATCH_SIZE=128

headline_data = np.random.uniform(low=1, high=9000, size=(MODEL_INPUT_BATCH_SIZE, 100)).astype(np.float32)
headline_data.shape
lstm_data = headline_data.reshape(MODEL_INPUT_BATCH_SIZE,1,100)
additional_data = np.random.uniform(low=1, high=9000, size=(MODEL_INPUT_BATCH_SIZE, 5)).astype(np.float32)
labels = np.random.randint(0, 1 + 1, size=(MODEL_INPUT_BATCH_SIZE, 1))

main_input = Input(shape=(1,100), dtype='float32', name='main_input')

lstm_out = LSTM(32)(main_input)

auxiliary_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(lstm_out)

auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(5,), name='aux_input')
x = keras.layers.concatenate([lstm_out, auxiliary_input])

# We stack a deep densely-connected network on top
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

# And finally we add the main logistic regression layer
main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

# This defines a model with two inputs and two outputs:
model = Model(inputs=[main_input, auxiliary_input], outputs=[main_output, auxiliary_output])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                loss={'main_output': 'binary_crossentropy', 'aux_output': 'binary_crossentropy'},
                loss_weights={'main_output': 1., 'aux_output': 0.2})

# And trained it via:
model.fit({'main_input': lstm_data, 'aux_input': additional_data},
                {'main_output': labels, 'aux_output': labels},
                epochs=1000, batch_size=TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE)
```

Comment: I have read that post a 100 times :( - maybe I am being a bit stupid, but, when I reshape it to (128,1,100), I get `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4` which is ridiculous because earlier it said it should be 3 not 2! I will read the post again!

Comment: Hmm maybe my answer is wrong, i will have to verify

Comment: I am not sure your answer is wrong either because the link you posted also makes the same input shape. It is just weird. btw: the above code is from the keras tutorial `https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models`, where I simply delete the embedding layer (because mine is a regression problem).

Comment: I have tried your update (I do `lstm_shape = headline_data.reshape(MODEL_INPUT_BATCH_SIZE,1,100)` and then `main_input = Input(shape=lstm_shape.shape, dtype='float32', name='main_input')`and it still gives me: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected main_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (128, 100)`.. I am so not sure why?!

Comment: and you use lstm_shape further in your code i assume? or?

Comment: no I dont use lstm_shape anywhere else other than main_inputs. where else do I need to use it? the error seems to say that the problem is in main_input...

Comment: it should only be the main input so that's ok, try to copy paste my code.

Comment: it works perfectly. but, what have you done? :( LSTM input shape now is (1,100), but what does this shape imply? timesteps,features? why the `1`? Can you explain? I want to learn what is going on :(

Comment: The three needed dimensions are: Samples, timesteps & features.

In this case we assume that you have a single feature (or signal) which is why it is 1.


Seeing as you have random data, it's a bit hard to explain but if you used actual timeseries data it would be easier to understand.

Comment: thank you VERY much for this help. I will now try with a real timeseries (I used random data to get used to the shapes).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179889/discussion-between-vegardkt-and-johnj).